# How can I remove my Test Classes from my ShrinkWrap Archive

Tags: java, shrinkwrap

How can I filter classes out of my final archive?

```
public static JavaArchive unitTestJar() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create( JavaArchive.class )
            .addAsManifestResource( EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml" )
            .addPackages( false, getCorePackages() );
}

public static String[] getCorePackages( String... args ) {
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(
            "com.lm.util",
            "com.lm.infrastructure"
    );

    strings.addAll( Arrays.asList( args ) );
    return (String[]) strings.toArray();
}
```

I see that there's a [Filter API](https://docs.jboss.org/shrinkwrap/1.0.0-cr-3/), but I can't seem to find any examples of how to use it. Ultimately I figured I'd just remove anything that is `*Test*`. Which is easier than trying to add a class at a time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)  
          .addPackages(true, Filters.exclude(".*Test.class"), getCorePackages());
```

Comment: @Sam, The question is about API usage. In this case, I don't see any better help than a testable example.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that - I was reviewing answers / questions in the StackOverflow Review section. Unfortunately, it didn't show me the context of the answer.

Comment: This regexp, `.*Test.*`, will also exclude any class with a name containing the word "Test", which is not necessarily a JUnit test file. Use `.*Test.class` to exclude only the files with a name ending with `Test`.